# Пропал модуль maven из IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Пропал модуль Maven из IDEA, как его можно обратно добавить в идею?
[image: нет сборщика maven[![][1]]
[image: нет сборщика maven[![][2]]

Answer (score 1):

На случай если у кого-нибудь возникнет эта проблема. Устанавливаем пакет Maven, прописываем переменные среды. В IDEA Settings->Plugins подключаем Maven Integration и Maven Integration Extension.